# SQL sum() with multiple level joins

Tags: sql

Let's say I have the following table relationships (via keys existing on both ends)

```
table a -> table b
table b -> table c
table c -> table d
table d -> table e
table e -> table f
```

And I want to group by a key on `table a` and sum() values from `table f` as if both tables were directly joined.

Problem is that if I do that, information will be duplicated as all relationships from a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f will repeat (as Andomar said: some information repeats because there are multiple routes from A to F)

Is there a way around that, or is my only choice to create a middle table containing the `table a` -> `table f` relationship?

Details:

```
Table a
id1 | id2

Table b
id2 | id3

Table c
id3 | value

select a.id1, sum(value) from a 
inner join b on a.id2 = b.id2
inner join c on b.id3 = c.id3
group by a.id1
```

Data example:

Doing the join, the relationship is:

```
a b c value
1 2 2 20
1 3 2 20
1 4 2 20
```

If I do the sum(), I will get 60 but I want to get 20

Thanks

Comment: I think we will need more information about the table structures and keys

Comment: Edit: I've added a detail in the question. The question doesn't really require that level of detail, the question applies to all sets of tables. Simply assume table a is linked to table b via some column, table b is linked to table c via another column, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "information will be duplicated"? What information? If you're doing inner-joins along the way, you should get a single copy of each common row between each two tables.

Comment: That's what John means by needing more information about your tables; we need to know what information is duplicating for you since you might be looking at it from the wrong angle.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question. Editing...

Comment: "`keys on both ends`" doesn';t tell us anything... We need to know for each relationship which side is the "Unique" Key. If "recordes are being suplicated" then it sounds like you are performing joins using an insufficient foreign Key, or your Join conditions do not include a unique key on one end. This could be what is causing cartesian products

Comment: Ok, I will include all these details now. I think you are right, it is due to many-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that some information repeats because there are multiple routes from A to F.  If there is a unique key in F, you can un-duplicate the routes using a subquery:

```
SELECT  SubQuery.AValue, sum(SubQuery.FValue)
FROM    (
        SELECT a.value as AValue, f.key, f.value as FValue
        FROM a
        INNER JOIN b ON b.key = a.key
        INNER JOIN c ON c.key = b.key
        INNER JOIN d ON d.key = c.key
        INNER JOIN e ON e.key = d.key
        INNER JOIN f ON f.key = e.key
        GROUP BY a.value, f.key, f.value
        ) as SubQuery
GROUP BY SubQuery.AValue
```

The subquery ensures each row in F is only counted once.

Comment: Hi Andomar, thank's a lot. So SQL doesn't have special syntax to say I want the unique routes between A to F in the language